Calling API on landscape, not getting the right response
I tried following the article on how to call API:
https://ubuntu.com/landscape/docs/make-rest-api-requests
curl -X POST "https://your-landscape.domain.com/api/v2/login" -d '{"email": "jane@example.com", "password": "jane-pwd", "account": "standalone"}'
but my response comes out as Query API Service. It does not match from the example provided in the article.
Even when I remove the payload, it will go to Query API Service
username@hostname:~$ curl -X POST "https://landscape-site.com/api/v2/login" -d '{"email": "email", "password": "pwd", "account": "standalone")'
Query API Service

My intended goal was to check the computer whether they have Ubuntu Pro through API
https://ubuntu.com/landscape/docs/api-rest-computers
The legacy API (CLI, python, etc) works fine but does not show ubuntu_pro_info, so I wanted to try the curl method. How can I get the API to get it to work on curl? This is on Ubuntu 22.04. and the landscape server 23.03.

Please edit the question and add what version of Ubuntu are you using.

Turns out landscape server needs to be on version 24.
Version 23 is not supported.
